# how to specify consumer group in Kafka Spark Streaming using direct stream

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

How to specify consumer group id for kafka spark streaming using direct stream API.

```
HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "app1");

    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc, 
            String.class, 
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class, 
            StringDecoder.class, 
            kafkaParams, 
            topicsSet
    );
```

though i have specified the configuration not sure if missing something. using spark1.3

```
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "app1");
```

Comment: It should be exactly as you're doing it.

Comment: What do you mean by `not sure if missing something`? Please ask a specific question. Something like *I tried X to achieve Y using library Z but got exception E with stacktrace S* is appropriate from StackOverflow.

Comment: @DebosmitRay I tried "group.id" using spark kafka direct stream to specify consumer group. Not getting any exception but want to know if this the right way to specify consumer group while using createDirectStream API method. Does it help now???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct stream API use the low level Kafka API, and as so doesn't use consumer groups in anyway. If you want to use consumer groups with Spark Streaming, you'll have to use the receiver based API.

[Full details are available in the doc !](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: Will i still be able to consume the data with  multiple applications using the direct stream API? without any data loss to each of the application?

Answer (score 5):

`createDirectStream` in `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8` does not support group mode, because it's using the low-level Kafka API.

But `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` supports group mode.

[Consumer Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs)

> In 0.9.0.0 we introduced the new Java consumer as a replacement for the older Scala-based simple and high-level consumers. The configs for both new and old consumers are described below.

In the `New Consumer Configs`, it has the `group.id` item.

The `Spark Streaming integration for Kafka 0.10` is using the new API. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

> The Spark Streaming integration for Kafka 0.10 is similar in design to the 0.8 Direct Stream approach. It provides simple parallelism, 1:1 correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions, and access to offsets and metadata. However, because the newer integration uses the new Kafka consumer API instead of the simple API, there are notable differences in usage.

I've tested the group mode in `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10`, it does work.