# How does pyspark kafka know where it starts to consume data if not set group id?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I run pyspark structured streaming without specifying the kafka group id, and I find the group.id is always changed in the logger message when I run the program every time. I confused that if it changes the group.id, how does it know where it starts to consume next time, or should I manually set the offset of kafka? And how do I know its automatic generated topic id is conflict to other topic id which is manually set by myself?

Comment: whenever you are restarting is your consumer reading the data from beginning of the topic?

Comment: I don't know, and the kafka Web UI cannot see the offset and the group id

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to read [consumers](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers) section from the official Kafka documentation:

> Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on separate machines.
>
> If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then the records will effectively be load balanced over the consumer instances.
>
> If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes.

Every consumer group has own offset. If you do not specify consumer group.id, then every time you runs your program a new consumer group id will be generated and assigned to your consumer client. In this way, you always will start reading messages from the begging (offset=0).

If you want to continue reading from last offset you need to use the same group.id as before.

Every topic can have multiple consumer groups. You can list them:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

and describe some specific group:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group mygroup --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Comment: In fact, spark structured streaming cannot set group id, it generated a group id every time when you run the program, and it consumes kafka data from the latest offset.

Comment: Do you have something related to the `application.id`? This ID is used in the following places to isolate resources used by the application from others. For example as the Kafka consumer group.id for coordination.

Comment: Check out https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#id4 `application.id` section. When an application is updated, the application.id should be changed unless you want to reuse the existing data in internal topics and state stores. For example, you could embed the version information within application.id, as my-app-v1.0.0 and my-app-v1.0.2. Maybe it can helps you.

Comment: Also this looks helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/36529679/8330509